# how does the operating system treat few interrupts and keep processes going?

Tags: operating-system, interrupt

I'm learning computer organization and structure (I'm using Linux OS with x86-64 architecture). we've studied that when an interrupt occurs in user mode, the OS is notified and it switches between the user stack and the kernel stack by loading the kernels rsp from the TSS, afterwards it saves the necessary registers (such as rip) and in case of software interrupt it also saves the error-code. in the end, just before jumping to the adequate handler routine it zeroes the TF and in case of hardware interrupt it zeroes the IF also. I wanted to ask about few things:

1. the error code is save in the rip, so why loading both?
2. if I consider a case where few interrupts happen together which causes the IF and TF to turn on, if I zero the TF and IF, but I treat only one interrupt at a time, aren't I leave all the other interrupts untreated? in general, how does the OS treat few interrupts that occur at the same time when using the method of IDT with specific vector for each interrupt?
   does this happen because each program has it's own virtual memory and thus the interruption handling processes of all the programs are unrelated? where can i read more about it?
3. how does an operating system keep other necessary progresses running while handling the interrupt?

thank you very much for your time and attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. the error code is save in the rip, so why loading both?

You're misunderstanding some things about the error code. Specifically:

- it's not generated by software interrupts (e.g. instructions like `int 0x80`)
- it is generated by some exceptions (page fault, general protection fault, double fault, etc).
- the error code (if used) is not saved in the RIP, it's pushed on the stack so that the exception handler can use it to get more information about the cause of the exception

> 2a. if I consider a case where few interrupts happen together which causes the IF and TF to turn on, if I zero the TF and IF, but I treat only one interrupt at a time, aren't I leave all the other interrupts untreated?

When the IF flag is clear, mask-able IRQs (which doesn't include other types of interrupts - software interrupts, exceptions) are postponed (not disabled) until the IF flag is set again. They're "temporarily untreated" until they're treated later.

The TF flag only matters for debugging (e.g. single-step debugging, where you want the CPU to generate a trap after every instruction executed). It's only cleared in case the process (in user-space) was being debugged, so that you don't accidentally continue debugging the kernel itself; but most processes aren't being debugged like this so most of the time the TF flag is already clear (and clearing it when it's already clear doesn't really do anything).

> 2b. in general, how does the OS treat few interrupts that occur at the same time when using the method of IDT with specific vector for each interrupt? does this happen because each program has it's own virtual memory and thus the interruption handling processes of all the programs are unrelated? where can i read more about it?

There's complex rules that determine when an interrupt can interrupt (including when it can interrupt another interrupt). These rules mostly only apply to IRQs (not software interrupts that the kernel won't ever use itself, and not exceptions which are taken as soon as they occur). Understanding the rules means understanding the IF flag and the interrupt controller (e.g. how interrupt vectors and the "task priority register" in the local APIC influence the "processor priority register" in the local APIC, which determines which groups of IRQs will be postponed when the IF flag is set). Information about this can be obtained from Intel's manuals, but how Linux uses it can only be obtained from Linux source code and/or Linux specific documentation.

On top of that there's "whatever mechanisms and practices the OS felt like adding on top" (e.g. deferred procedure calls, tasklets, softIRQs, additional stack management) that add more complications (which can also only be obtained from Linux source code and/or Linux specific documentation).

*Note: I'm not a Linux kernel developer so can't/won't provide links to places to look for Linux specific documentation.*

> 3. how does an operating system keep other necessary progresses running while handling the interrupt?

A single CPU can't run 2 different pieces of code (e.g. an interrupt handler and user-space code) at the same time. Instead it runs them one at a time (e.g. runs user-space code, then switches to an IRQ handler for very short amount of time, then returns to the user-space code). Because the IRQ handler only runs for a very short amount of time it creates the illusion that everything is happening at the same time (even though it's not).

Of course when you have multiple CPUs, different CPUs can/do run different pieces of code at the same time.